# Shifted Brush Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to use Canvas in Javascript to draw something in a blank rectangle, but all I got is a shifted brush like this: https://i.imgur.com/s7g34wi.gifv

Here is my code:

```js
    var canvasE = {
    canvas : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx : canvas.getContext("2d"),
    rect : canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    mouse : {x: 0, y: 0},


    
    initCanvas(){
        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            canvasE.mouse.x = e.offsetX
            canvasE.mouse.y = e.offsetY
        }, false);

        canvasE.ctx.lineWidht = 3;
        canvasE.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        canvasE.ctx.lineCap = "round";
        canvasE.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            canvasE.ctx.beginPath();
            canvasE.ctx.moveTo(canvasE.mouse.x, canvasE.mouse.y);
            canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);
    
        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            canvasE.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);

        onPaint = function() {
            canvasE.ctx.lineTo(canvasE.mouse.x, canvasE.mouse.y);
            canvasE.ctx.stroke();
        }
    },

    clear(){
        canvasE.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    },}
    
canvasE.initCanvas();
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You misspelled `lineWidth` at around line 15 in the code you have given. You are also missing a few semicolons (lines 11 & 12)

Comment: So it looks like in trying to create a reproduceable example, I actually stumbled upon your error. Looks like you need to not use CSS width/heights, as it distorts the context width/heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your CSS. NEVER, EVER specify width and height for a `<canvas>` using CSS. Always specify it inside of the `<canvas>` tag. I fixed it:

```js
var canvasE = {
    canvas : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx : canvas.getContext("2d"),
    rect : canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    mouse : {x: 0, y: 0},


    
    initCanvas(){
        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            canvasE.mouse.x = e.offsetX;
            canvasE.mouse.y = e.offsetY;
        }, false);

        canvasE.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        canvasE.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        canvasE.ctx.lineCap = "round";
        canvasE.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            canvasE.ctx.beginPath();
            canvasE.ctx.moveTo(canvasE.mouse.x, canvasE.mouse.y);
            canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);
    
        canvasE.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            canvasE.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
        }, false);

        onPaint = function() {
            canvasE.ctx.lineTo(canvasE.mouse.x, canvasE.mouse.y);
            canvasE.ctx.stroke();
        }
    },

    clear(){
        canvasE.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    },}
    
canvasE.initCanvas();
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

I also fixed the errors I mentioned in my comment :)

Comment: That was actually me that added the style tags, to try and create a working reproducable example :(

Comment: Oh ok, but I still have a problem, I need to specify the width in percentage to fix my responsive.

Comment: Can't you just set the width and height dynamically?